# Проблема с адаптивностью сцены three.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bootstrap, three.js

На сайте проблема с адаптивностью сцены three js, я подписываюсь на изменение размеров окна и прописываю renderer.setSize(canvas.width,canvas.height) . Но сцена увеличивается вне зависимости от изменения окна(в меньшую или большую сторону). Кто может подсказать в чем проблема?

Все тестировалось в браузере Opera, система windows. Сервер на Node JS.

```
https://pastebin.com/uiVmwaVw
```

Comment: А как выглядит html? `const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});`, тут `canvas` берется из html.

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046955/4045502

Comment: Благодарю, помогло

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)